# Recommended Remote Desktop clients (Windows RDP)

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I'm in search of a good Mac RDP client for connecting to Windows machines. I've tried all of the ones I can find (CoRD, MSFT RDP, Thinomenon). I like CoRD the best, but it doesn't work for me any longer due to lack of NLA support.

I have over a dozen Windows machines I connect to regularly, and CoRD's tabbed interface was the best I'd been able to find for quickly connecting to machines and switching between them.

Any other suggestions from the hive mind?